# How do I make a dictionary that stores data as a list? [More complicated]

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a problem with dictionaries that I need help with.

Here is an excerpt from weather.txt:

```
Hail : 1 : xxx
Hail : 2 : xxx
Hail : 3 : xxx
Rain : 1 : xxx
Rain : 2 : xxx
Rain : 3 : xxx
```

The first value is the **weather**, the second value is the **intensity** and the third is just a short **description**.

Here is an excerpt from my game:

```
weather = open("weather.txt")

weather_list = {}

for line in weather:
    line = line.rstrip().split(":")
    weather_list[line[0][int(line[1]) -1]] = (line[0], line[1], line[2])

for key, value in weather_list.items():
    print key, ":", value
```

That prints this:

```
a : ('Rain ', ' 2 ', ' xxx')
i : ('Rain ', ' 3 ', ' xxx')
H : ('Hail ', ' 1 ', ' xxx')
R : ('Rain ', ' 1 ', ' xxx')
```

But I want it to print this:

```
'Rain': [('Rain ', ' 1 ', ' xxx'), ('Rain ', ' 2 ', ' xxx'), i : ('Rain ', ' 3 ', ' xxx')]
'Hail': etc...
```

I know my issue is with the syntax "weather_list[line[0][int(line[1]) -1]]". What I want it to do is have 1 key for each **weather**, and each value to be a tuple or list containing all the values for that **weather**, sorted by **intensity**, (intensity 1, intensity 2, intensity 3).

Any and all help is appreciated. Hope I explained it better this time.

Comment: Your whole question sounds completely uncomplicated (since you can easily have a dict with string keys and list values) except for this one sneaky sentence where you say "all foods have the same name etc. etc." -- what does that mean? If the key is the same for multiple lists, you'll have to find a new key to differentiate them. Otherwise the answer is: you just do it.

Comment: `{'key': []}`? But I'm not sure what your problem is - you could potentially have an easier time with another approach, depending on how you want to manipulate/search/whatever the data.

Comment: Better yet a dict of dicts: `food = {'apples': {'calories': 75, 'carbs': 0, 'tasty': True}, 'licorice': {'calories': 150, 'carbs': 0, 'tasty': False}}`. Sorry I don't actually know the calories or carbs or anything and apologies to any licorice fans.

Comment: dict(set(listoffood)) ?

Comment: @Matt please [edit] your question with the contents of `food.txt` and `food.py`. Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

This works:

```
weather = {}
with open('weather.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        data = line.strip().split(':')
        weather.setdefault(data[0], []).append(tuple(data))

weather = {key: sorted(value, key=lambda x: x[1]) for key, value in weather.items()}
```

The result looks like this:

```
>>> weather
{'Hail ': [('Hail ', ' 1 ', ' xxx'),
  ('Hail ', ' 2 ', ' xxx'),
  ('Hail ', ' 3 ', ' xxx')],
 'Rain ': [('Rain ', ' 1 ', ' xxx'),
  ('Rain ', ' 2 ', ' xxx'),
  ('Rain ', ' 3 ', ' xxx')]}
```

### Variation

The above solution has, as requested, redundant information for `Rain` and `Hail`. This version does not store them as first element in tuple but only as key in the dictionary:

```
weather = {}
with open('weather.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        data = line.strip().split(':')
        weather.setdefault(data[0], []).append(tuple(data[1:]))

weather = {key: sorted(value) for key, value in weather.items()}
```

The sorting is simpler and the result looks like this:

```
>>> weather
{'Hail ': [(' 1 ', ' xxx'), (' 2 ', ' xxx'), (' 3 ', ' xxx')],
 'Rain ': [(' 1 ', ' xxx'), (' 2 ', ' xxx'), (' 3 ', ' xxx')]}
```